# How to know when user unlinked google assistant actions?

Tags: google-home

I would like to handle unlinked user in backend. How can I know when user unlinked the actions in Assistant Directory?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer can be solved through the action.devices.DISCONNECT intent. This intent is triggered to inform you when a user has unlinked their device account from Google Assistant, you can also check the official documentation from Google at https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/intent/disconnect?hl=en in order to get a detailed clarification. If you need information about the request & response syntax in Node.js & Java as well (& not just JSON syntax) refer to the following link, https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/process-intents?hl=en#unlink